# About time travelling, multiply yourself

Tags: time-travel

About time travelling, if I go back one year, find my past self, wait until a little before I first went back in time (11 months and 29 days) and both of us go back, we keep repeating this until we populate the world.

To better explain the question: I'm going back in time, meeting myself, we join together, wait nearly a year, then we go back in time again, join our earlier selves, wait almost another year and then go back again and we keep doing this until we have an army of me.

The point is, is this viable? What kind of time travel is the best fit for doing that?

Comment: about the 11 , are months, and 29 are days

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I don't understand what if anything you are trying to ask here.

Comment: to populate the world?

Comment: @Vincent i assumed that was what OP meant, but even then there isn't really a question, more the start of one

Comment: Just nitpicking, but if you went back March 1'st, than 11 months and 29 days later would be March 1'st again (28 days of February plus 1).

Comment: Also, the answer to this question depends on which theory of time you use. If you use parallel time lines, You could go back in time, team up with your self, go further back in time, kill yourself, and you'll be just fine because each copy of you is from a different distinct timeline. (so you can make as many copies of yourself as you want with your age/health being the only factor)

Comment: Consider clarifying the process of time travel.  For example, do you need a Tardis to do it?  If so, what are you going to do when there's so many of you that you fill it up (it's bigger on the inside, but it's not limitless).  If you just need any old police box, how many police boxes can be made in 11 months and 29 days?  As you answer these questions, you will likely find your answer in the implementation details that result.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? At the moment, you're just stating that you went back in time over and over again so that you have multiple copies of yourself.

Comment: ok i raised the point , to see if its at all possible someway, or if somebody see some "bug" in the idea.

Comment: about the ammout of people inside the time machine its another question that i could think latter. My be go back , find miself with machine and we both go even furher back......

Answer (score 1):

With every run, you would be 1 year older. In order to match with current world population, you will have to do 32 runs. Some of yourselves would be 32 year older than you have started and one of them would be one year older. This project would need a time machine with a capacity of 3.5 billion, otherwise some would get behind and the project would take significantly longer.

Comment: Please note that this may violate some physics rules that I am not aware of.

Comment: All of them.  All of the rules.

Comment: Well without explanation why, calling all of them is not very helpful

Comment: @Tal All of them! Really? I agree with Cem Kalyoncu, unless you can explain how it violating physics then your statement isn't helpful. Anyone who looks at the hypothetical physical models of time travel will be aware that time travel bends known physics but doesn't break it.

Comment: Small wearable time machines will enable this serial doubling process to work without violating too much physics. Classical causality will be a bit wobbly around the knees, but time travel's like that.

Comment: This is why I hate time traveling stories :(  It never make's sense to me.

Comment: Actually, there is a time travel system that makes sense. It is used in many stories including the mind boggling Donnie Darko. In this system, time heals itself, mending any changes so that all the changes that are done creates a perfect loop. 3.5 billion time travellers will still be hard to swallow.